# What's the meaning of "shide" in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

There is a sentence in a book i am reading currently:

‘Doh. I wanna finish this head-choppin’ stuff and leave this shide
down.’

The character is telling his mafia boss to go into a place and behead the man they want to kill, but his boss tells him to wait. Afterwards he says this sentence. He is using a slang language as you can see and i couldn't understand "leave this shide down" part in the sentence.

He also says "Bloody shide down" before he swings his sword to kill the man. I would be delighted if you can help me with this word. Is this a slang or deformed word in English? Because its lexical meanings have nothing to do with the context.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the guy's got a lisp?

Comment: Does he intend to give up on his current line of work, i.e leave mafia and all ? Which book is it ?

Comment: JonMark Perry, 

my mother language is not English, so i am not sure if he's got a lisp or not, but here is a sentence he says: "Whad are we waidin’ for, eh?’"

Comment: Rahul, the guy comes from another city to help them so yes, he wants to finish his work and go back as soon as possible. The book is Macbeth by Jo Nesbo.

Comment: @geven: No. What I mean is does he totally wanna leave this job after this work ?

Comment: @Rahul: No, he doesn't want it. What would you offer if he wanted it? I want to hear it anyway.

Comment: @geven: [**Shide**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shide_(Shinto)) is a zigzag piece of paper used in Japanese shrines. Maybe it used a slang for a dagger, knife as they have zigzag teeth. I thought he wanna do this as final job and leave profession. Thus leave that **shide** (_knife_) down.

Comment: Also from _"Whad are we waidin’ for, eh?’"_ I guess he is pronouncing **t** as **d** .So he might be trying to say is **shit town**. _leave this shit town_.

Comment: @Rahul: I think your second suggestion sounds better. Because there is no reference to zigzag teeth, his weapon is a simple sword. Thank you so much.

Comment: @geven: Lookout for more instances where he pronounces **t** as **d**.

Comment: I think shide is actually 'shite' which is a UK word which makes to me as the author is European.

Comment: Can you give more context? What is the author/name of the book? Is the setting Us or UK and where within those places and what type of people are talking?

Comment: Jo Nesbo is Norwegian, so the book must be in translation.

Answer (score 3):

I think he's saying 'shite town'. i.e. shit town

That would fit with the context that he had come from another city to do the job and wanted to go back.

The mispronunciation of the 't's and use of 'shite' for shit suggests that the guy is Irish? Or Italian American? Or could he have a cold?

Comment: Given it's Macbeth, I would guess Nesbo is going for a Scottish accent, although I agree Irish would be a better fit.